# Minecraft 0.16.0 won't even try to connect to a server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this? I reinstalled Minecraft but I still got this

Answer (score -1):

The best solution to this would be to look up the ip address for your specific minecraft edition. Say you're in windows 10 0.16 but you have the address for a server in 0.15.9. No prob-- just look up the ip address for 0.16. This helped me with a bunch of servers.